# Visualizing BIG datasets with leaflet-heat

Tags: javascript, leaflet, clustering, heat-map

I am trying to find a fast method to visualize very BIG datasets (up to 1,6 Mio points) as a heatmap with javaScript. I tried to use [leaflet-heat.js](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat), but it is extremely slow with such a large number of points. I also tried [leaflet-clustering](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster), but on the beginning it is 10x slower as a heatmap and sometimes crashes (once the clusters are built, it is fast).

Any ideas how can a make a heatmap-layer that draws million of points fast?

Comment: I would use QGIS http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/creating_heatmaps.html